# Excel Macro to extrapolate depending on current time

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I am trying to write an Excel macro to extrapolate data when necessary. I will elaborate with the following example:

During the year, I receive data at the end of each month, fill it in the table below, to generate a line chart in Excel.

```
Jan.  Feb.  Mar.  Apr.  May  June  July  Aug.  Sept.  Oktob.  Nov.  Dec.
100   150   300    230   80   0     170
```

The resulting chart is:

[image]

I also receive the data once at the end of each week. If for example, it is the first week of July, and i enter the data into cell below July (50 instead 170), I want Excel to plot it at the specific position and to perform a linear extrapolation until July. Such as the outcome is:

[image]

Main question:

1. How can I use current data as a condition?
2. How can I insert a plot at a quarter, if the x-axis contains months as labels?

Comment: Does it truly need to be at the quarter point on the X-Axis? I've done something like this before, but simply plotted on the next month's X-Axis point. If it does, the workaround answer is your non-forecast series should only plot on every 4th spot on the X-axis, creating the effect that the forecast is on the 1/4 point. As far as current date, you can simply use the sheet formula `=TODAY()` to get the current date in the sheet and use that. In no way is VBA required for what you're trying to do.

Comment: I think it has to be at the quarter of the x-axis, since it will give hint about the extrapolation trend. If we plot it at the exact month, we will alwys have to keep in mind it is not the real final value.
As for VBA, I want to have a macro which will generate the chart every time the table is updated, while keeping the previously mentionned properties

Comment: Then you'll need to use the plotting every 4th point trick I mentioned. Since you don't ask about how to write the macro I'm assuming you have an idea of what to do there already. If not, you should update your question to include what you've tried & what specific issue(s) you're having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, the way to get the effect of plotting every 1/4 step of the X-axis in you forecast is to have the data series plotting actual (non-forecast) values every 4th step of the X-axis. This way, the forecast plotting every step looks like it's using smaller steps. To further the effect you may want to have labels on the X-axis only for every 4th step.